# How to execute git commands in parallel with Gradle script?

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

I'm trying to build a simple Gradle script that git clones many repos in parallel.
That's the code I came up with so far:

```
abstract class ParallelCloneTask extends org.gradle.api.DefaultTask {

    @Inject
    abstract WorkerExecutor getWorkerExecutor()

    @TaskAction
    def cloneRepos() {
        WorkQueue workQueue = getWorkerExecutor().noIsolation()
        List<String> paths = getRepoPaths()

        paths.each { path ->
            workQueue.submit(CloneSingleRepo.class) { CloneSingleRepoWorkParameter parameters ->
                parameters.getPath().set(path)
            }
        }
        println "Done"
    }}

abstract class CloneSingleRepo implements WorkAction<CloneSingleRepoWorkParameter> {

    @Override
    void execute() {
        String path = getParameters().getPath().get()
        String myCurrentDir = "/Users/myname/etc/"
        project.exec {
            workingDir "${myCurrentDir}"
            commandLine 'git', 'clone', "${path}"
        }
        println "Cloned repo ${path}"
    }

}

interface CloneSingleRepoWorkParameter extends WorkParameters {
    Property<String> getPath()
} 

task cloneRepos(type: ParallelCloneTask)
```

When I run this task, it fails because it doesn't find "project" variable in CloneSingleRepo's execute() method.
Why does that happen and how can I fix?

If I access "project" variable in cloneRepos() method directly, it works fine.

Comment: Instead of using `project.exec`, you should be able to `@Inject` `abstract ExecOperations getExecOperations()` into your work action class, and then call `execOperations.exec` inside your `execute` method

Comment: It works! Thank you so much, you saved my day! 
Unfortunately there's no much documentation about Worker API or maybe I missed it.